# Reduce collections in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql, reduce

I've got this query in JPQL:

```
select mail.content.attachments from Mail mail
```

It would return a list of sets, filled with `Attachment` entities.

However I want to receive a set that only contains the IDs of the `Attachment` entities. How can I achieve this with JPQL?

Comment: _"SELECT a.id FROM Mail m JOIN m.content c JOIN c.attachments a"_

Comment: *"It would return a list of sets"* - No, this JPQL is in fact invalid! The SELECT clause cannot contain multiple-valued elements, see JPA 2.1 ch. 4.8.